# Strange paint/rendering issue in Safari when scrolling a long list of items

Tags: css, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm having a very strange issue were a page with a grid of boxes has problems in Safari, Chrome on iPhone 11 pro, iPhone 13 pro, Chrome on Pixel 4a. Other devices seem fine.
Side effects: pages becomes unresponsive, parts of the page become blank when scrolling up and down.

See below a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a long investigation
Too many boxes… nop
Big images … nop
Grid issues … nop
Multiple re-renders …. nop
Lazy loading fixes it … nop
Virtualization, windowing .. nop nop

Is CSS the problem? yes `filter: drop-shadow(...)`
amazing :|

Comment: Thank you!! I've spent hours fighting this, searching to no avail. That drop-shadow was absolutely the problem.

Comment: Good to hear it's solved! My team spent 2 days on it.